# Determining significant growth

Tags: php, statistics

I have a collection of Facebook pages that I'm recording daily number of "Likes" for.

I'd like to identify those which are growing the fastest. Problem is that I'm wondering how to remove the 'noise' of pages with a small number of likes and those with a great number of likes.

[image: facebook likes chart]

Are there any general techniques or approaches for what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: you looking for [Standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) - reject values which  not in range of σ+/-average and you will be good

Comment: As to the small number of likes - why don't you just ignore all pages with less than 100? Not sure what you mean about the great number of likes though..

Comment: Hi, here is a javascript illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/TB4U3/2/ It simply extrapolates the measured data, then you could choose a time in the future, and sort the extrapolated data at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more or less statistically correct (and simple) answer is:

Assuming that the first measurement is x likes, the second is y likes,

Then the estimate of the natural logarithm of the growth is given by

log(y / x) with an error estimate of sqrt(1 / x + 1 / y)

But since you are interested in the conservative estimate of the growth, you should use something like  ~ 5% confidence interval. 
So I would recommend ranking your dataset using the folllowing function.
log(y / x) - 2 * sqrt(1 / x + 1 / y)

For example:

growth from 1 to 10 will get the score of 0.2

growth from 100 to 400 will get the score of 1.16

growth from 10000 to 15000 will get the score of 0.38

One of the important properties of this estimator will be that the growth 
from say 10000 to 100000 will be ranked higher than the grown from 1000 to 10000, which in turn will be ranked higher than the grown from 100 to 1000 etc...

Comment: One thing I don't understand is that given your example:

    log(10 / 1) - 2 * sqrt(1 / 1 + 1 / 10) = -1.09 | 
    log(400 / 100) - 2 * sqrt(1 / 100 + 1 / 400) = 0.37 | 
    log(15000 / 10000) - 2 * sqrt(1 / 10000 + 1 / 15000) = 0.15

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are apparently using log_10, while you supposed to be using natural ones.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to create a synthetic metric for growth which takes into account both percentage and absolute numbers.

I would suggest taking the base-10 logarithm of the # of likes on day 1 and multiplying it with the percentage growth to arrive at this "growth rank" as I'll call it.

[image]

If you look the "Final Metric" provides the biggest number for growth that you consider significant and smaller numbers for growth you don't consider significant.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of weighting applied to the growth percentage, I'd suggest log(B/10), so the metric you will rank by is:

```
score = log(B/10) * C
```

You can experiment with the constant term there and also the log base. A good tool for doing that in now is google, e.g. type this into a google search to see a plot of the weighting function:

```
y = log(x/10)
```

Or else grab a copy of gnuplot.